# How to use WOW.js in Angular 2 Webpack?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, wow.js

I know we need typings file for wow.js but I couldn't find it anywhere. Is there any other solution for loading this external js into webpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following steps:

1. Install [exports-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exports-loader/)

   ```
       npm i exports-loader --save-dev
   ```
2. Add to `webpack.config.js` this loader

   ```
       {
           test: require.resolve('wow.js/dist/wow.js'), 
           loader: 'exports?this.WOW'
       }
   ```
3. Create `typings.d.ts` file in your typings folder:

   ```
       declare module "wow.js/dist/wow.js" {
           var noTypeInfoYet: any;
           export = noTypeInfoYet;
       }
   ```
4. add import to your `*.component.ts` file

   ```
       import * as WOW from 'wow.js/dist/wow.js';
   ```
5. Use it well!

   ```
       ngOnInit(){
           new WOW().init();
       }
   ```

Of course you can use your own webpack configuration without `exports-loader`, etc...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try this as soon as I get my hands on Angular.