# How to setup WOW.js in Angular 2 and 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, wow.js

I am trying to get WOW.js working in my Angular project but it is not working yet. I am not using webpack so I think the next thread is not answering my question: [How to use WOW.js in Angular 2 Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826223/how-to-use-wow-js-in-angular-2-webpack).

The steps that I took until now:

1. I installed the wow.js module.

> npm install wowjs

2. I added the wowjs files to '.angular-cli.json'.

   "styles": [
       "../node_modules/wowjs/css/libs/animate.css" ],

   "scripts": [
   "../node_modules/wowjs/dist/wow.js" 
   ]

3.Then I added a wow effect to one of my headers.

```
<h1 class="wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s">Wow effect!</h1>
```

4. And the next thing I did was rebuilding and serving my project.

> ng build
>
> ng serve

5. There is no wow effect yet. Does somebody know what I have to do yet?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will need to initialise WOW for your component.

In the component where you plan on using WOW, import the script

```
 import { WOW } from 'wowjs/dist/wow.min';
```

then  in your class with the Angular method ngAfterViewInit

```
 class ngAfterViewInit(){

   new WOW().init();
 }
```